# Encoding::CompatibilityError incompatible encoding with this operation: UTF-16

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8, utf-16, incompatibility

I've been fighting with this for a second day now. Don't really have a code snippet to provide, as I have no idea where this exception occurs. I have this **Arachni** security scanning tool (written in ruby; can be found [here](https://github.com/Arachni/arachni)), and when I try to launch it against the web site, it throws an error with the message `[utilities#exception_jail:428] [Encoding::CompatibilityError] incompatible encoding with this operation: UTF-16`

and then there is a huge stack trace that doesn't tell me anything useful:

```
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser/nodes/with_value.rb:22:in `strip'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser/nodes/with_value.rb:22:in `value='
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser/nodes/with_value.rb:18:in `initialize'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser/sax.rb:58:in `new'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser/sax.rb:58:in `text'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser.rb:70:in `sax_html'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser.rb:70:in `block in parse'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/support/cache/base.rb:108:in `call'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/support/cache/base.rb:108:in `fetch'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser.rb:66:in `parse'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser.rb:243:in `document'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/parser.rb:423:in `paths'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/page.rb:309:in `paths'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/framework/parts/data.rb:207:in `push_paths_from_page'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/framework/parts/audit.rb:98:in `audit_page'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/framework/parts/audit.rb:228:in `audit_queues'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/framework/parts/audit.rb:202:in `block in audit'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/framework/parts/audit.rb:177:in `loop'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/framework/parts/audit.rb:177:in `audit'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/framework.rb:117:in `block in run'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/utilities.rb:425:in `call'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/utilities.rb:425:in `exception_jail'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/lib/arachni/framework.rb:117:in `run'
    [-] [utilities#exception_jail:428] D:/arachni-1.5.1-0.5.12-windows-x86_64/system/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/arachni-1.5.1/ui/cli/framework.rb:80:in `block in run'
```

Just to add another +2 cents - I'm completely new to Ruby and don't know much about their error handling system. I've tried to research online and got an idea that this particular error is thrown once 2 different encoded English-language-alien strings (for instance `ё` that gone through **UTF-8** and **UTF-16** encoding systems) are being compared to each other. I tried to come up with the guesses what might cause this:

1. Ruby (installed on my machine) encoding system is different from what Arachni uses. My ruby version is `2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x64-mingw32]` which is the latest stable version according to [this](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/). Arachni uses **UTF-8** encoding system, which doesn't differ from Ruby's one
2. Arachni encounters some string while scanning, that it can't encode using regular **UTF-8** system and requires something more powerful and complex to deal with (**UTF-16**)
3. Kind of crazy...but may be UTF-16 is not supported on my machine (using Windows 10)..

If anyone encountered something similar (not necessary with Arachni tool, but may be in general) and can navigate to the right direction, that will save half of my life.

Comment: Anyone? Any suggestions?

Comment: UTF-8 and UTF-16 are encoding of Unicode. Both similar powerful. Windows uses internally UTF-16. For rest: I have no idea: check the settings, try to force UTF-8